# I'm trying to make a side-scroller game and I'm struggling to infinitely spawn ground

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, swift2

> I have made it so that when you tap on the left or right side of the screen it will move accordingly by moving the worldNode

```
import SpriteKit
import UIKit
import GameplayKit

var ground = Ground(imageNamed: "grass.png")
var sceneBody = SKPhysicsBody()

enum BodyType:UInt32 {
    case Player = 1
    case Wall = 2
    case Ground = 4
    case AnotherObject = 8
    case AnotherObject2 = 16
    case AnotherObject3 = 32
    case AnotherObject4 = 64

}



class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate{

    var player = Player(imageNamed: "p1_walk02.png")
    let theCamera: SKCameraNode = SKCameraNode()
    var textAtlas = SKTextureAtlas()
    var textArry = [SKTexture]()
    var worldNode = SKNode()






    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0, -9.8)
        physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self



        self.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0)
        self.backgroundColor = SKColor.whiteColor()

        //self.camera?.position = player.position

        addChild(worldNode)

        let spawn = SKAction.runBlock({
            () in

            self.makeGU1()

        })

        let delay = SKAction.waitForDuration(2)

        let seq = SKAction.sequence([spawn, delay])

        worldNode.runAction(SKAction.repeatAction(seq, count: 1))

        self.addChild(player)

        player.xScale = 0.5
        player.yScale = 0.5
        player.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width*0.3, y: ground.position.y+56)

        worldNode.position = self.position
        worldNode.xScale = self.xScale
        worldNode.yScale = self.yScale


    }

    func scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(){
        //Scheduling timer to Call the function **Countdown** with the interval of 1 seconds
        let myTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.5, target: self, selector: Selector("updateCounting"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
    func updateCounting() {

    }


    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        for touch in touches {
            let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
            print(location)

            //-7.49999237060547
            if player.position.x > 230.499969482422{

            }
            if location.x >  self.frame.width/2 {
                // Left side of the screen
                textAtlas = SKTextureAtlas(named: "Walk")

                for i in 1...textAtlas.textureNames.count{
                    let Name = "p1_walk0\(i).png"
                    textArry.append(SKTexture(imageNamed: Name))
                }
                let Animate = SKAction.animateWithTextures(textArry, timePerFrame: 0.1)
                player.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(Animate), withKey: "Left run")
                print(location)
                worldNode.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.moveBy(CGVectorMake(1000, 0), duration: 4).reversedAction()), withKey: "moveLeft")
                self.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.moveBy(CGVectorMake(1000, 0), duration: 4).reversedAction()), withKey: "moveLeft")


            } else {
                textAtlas = SKTextureAtlas(named: "Walk")

                for i in 1...textAtlas.textureNames.count{
                    let Name = "p1_walk0\(i).png"
                    textArry.append(SKTexture(imageNamed: Name))

                }
                let Animate = SKAction.animateWithTextures(textArry, timePerFrame: 0.1)
                player.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(Animate), withKey: "Left run")
                print(location)
                worldNode.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.moveBy(CGVectorMake(1000, 0), duration: 4)), withKey: "moveLeft")
                self.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.moveBy(CGVectorMake(1000, 0), duration: 4)), withKey: "moveLeft")

            }
        }
    }




    override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        player.removeActionForKey("Left run")
        var tex = [SKTexture]()
        tex.append(SKTexture(imageNamed:"p1_walk02.png"))
        player.runAction(SKAction.animateWithTextures(tex, timePerFrame: 0.2))
        worldNode.removeActionForKey("moveLeft")
        self.removeActionForKey("moveLeft")

    }




    func makeGU1(){
```

> This is where I set up the scene

```
        var ground1 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "grass.png")
        var ground2 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "grass.png")
        var ground0 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "grass.png")
        var ground3 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "grass.png")
        var ground4 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "grass.png")
        var ground5 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "grass.png")
        var ground6 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "grass.png")
        var ground7 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "grass.png")
        var ground8 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "grass.png")
        var ground9 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "grass.png")
        var ground10 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "grass.png")
        var ground11 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "grass.png")
        var ground12 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "grass.png")
        var ground13 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "grass.png")




                    ground0.xScale = 0.7
                    ground0.yScale = 0.7

                    ground0.position = CGPoint(x: 20, y: 10)

                    worldNode.addChild(ground0)

                    ground0.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: ground0.size)
                    ground0.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
                    ground0.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
                    ground0.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = BodyType.Ground.rawValue
                    ground0.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = BodyType.Player.rawValue
                    ground0.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = BodyType.Player.rawValue
                    ground0.copy()

                    ground1 = ground0.copy() as! SKSpriteNode
                    ground1.position = CGPoint(x: ground0.position.x+ground1.size.width, y: 10)
                    ground1.copy()

                    worldNode.addChild(ground1)









                    ground2.xScale = 0.7
                    ground2.yScale = 0.7

                    ground2.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: ground2.size)
                    ground2.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
                    ground2.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
                    ground2.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = BodyType.Ground.rawValue
                    ground2.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = BodyType.Player.rawValue
                    ground2.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = BodyType.Player.rawValue
                    ground2.position = CGPoint(x: ground1.position.x+ground2.size.width, y: 10)

                    worldNode.addChild(ground2)



                    ground3.xScale = 0.7
                    ground3.yScale = 0.7

                    ground3.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: ground3.size)
                    ground3.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
                    ground3.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
                    ground3.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = BodyType.Ground.rawValue
                    ground3.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = BodyType.Player.rawValue
                    ground3.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = BodyType.Player.rawValue
                    ground3.position = CGPoint(x: ground2.position.x+ground3.size.width, y: 10)

                    worldNode.addChild(ground3)



                    ground4.xScale = 0.7
                    ground4.yScale = 0.7

                    ground4.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: ground4.size)
                    ground4.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
                    ground4.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
                    ground4.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = BodyType.Ground.rawValue
                    ground4.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = BodyType.Player.rawValue
                    ground4.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = BodyType.Player.rawValue
                    ground4.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
                    ground4.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
                    ground4.position = CGPoint(x: ground3.position.x+ground4.size.width, y: 10)

                    worldNode.addChild(ground4)



                    ground5.xScale = 0.7
                    ground5.yScale = 0.7

                    ground5.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: ground5.size)

                    ground5.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = BodyType.Ground.rawValue
                    ground5.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = BodyType.Player.rawValue
                    ground5.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = BodyType.Player.rawValue
                    ground5.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
                    ground5.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
                    ground5.position = CGPoint(x: ground4.position.x+ground5.size.width, y: 10)

                    worldNode.addChild(ground5)



                    ground6.xScale = 0.7
                    ground6.yScale = 0.7
                    ground6.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: ground6.size)
                    ground6.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
                    ground6.physicsBody?.dynamic = false

                    ground6.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = BodyType.Ground.rawValue
                    ground6.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = BodyType.Player.rawValue
                    ground6.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = BodyType.Player.rawValue

                    ground6.position = CGPoint(x: ground5.position.x+ground6.size.width, y: 10)

                    worldNode.addChild(ground6)



                    ground7.xScale = 0.7
                    ground7.yScale = 0.7
                    ground7.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: ground6.size)
                    ground6.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
                    ground7.physicsBody?.dynamic = false

                    ground7.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = BodyType.Ground.rawValue
                    ground7.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = BodyType.Player.rawValue
                    ground7.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = BodyType.Player.rawValue

                    ground7.position = CGPoint(x: ground6.position.x+ground7.size.width, y: 10)
                    worldNode.addChild(ground7)



                    ground8.xScale = 0.7
                    ground8.yScale = 0.7
                    ground8.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: ground8.size)
                    ground8.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
                    ground8.physicsBody?.dynamic = false

                    ground8.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = BodyType.Ground.rawValue
                    ground8.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = BodyType.Player.rawValue
                    ground8.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = BodyType.Player.rawValue

                    ground8.position = CGPoint(x: ground7.position.x+ground8.size.width, y: 10)

                    worldNode.addChild(ground8)



                    ground9.xScale = 0.7
                    ground9.yScale = 0.7
                    ground9.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: ground9.size)
                    ground9.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
                    ground9.physicsBody?.dynamic = false

                    ground9.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = BodyType.Ground.rawValue
                    ground9.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = BodyType.Player.rawValue
                    ground9.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = BodyType.Player.rawValue

                    ground9.position = CGPoint(x: ground8.position.x+ground9.size.width, y: 10)
                    worldNode.addChild(ground9)




                    ground10.xScale = 0.7
                    ground10.yScale = 0.7
                    ground10.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: ground10.size)
                    ground10.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
                    ground10.physicsBody?.dynamic = false

                    ground10.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = BodyType.Ground.rawValue
                    ground10.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = BodyType.Player.rawValue
                    ground10.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = BodyType.Player.rawValue

                    ground10.position = CGPoint(x: ground9.position.x+ground10.size.width, y: 10)
                    worldNode.addChild(ground10)



                    ground11.xScale = 0.7
                    ground11.yScale = 0.7
                    ground11.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: ground11.size)
                    ground11.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = BodyType.Ground.rawValue
                    ground11.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = BodyType.Player.rawValue
                    ground11.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = BodyType.Player.rawValue
                    ground11.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
                    ground11.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
                    ground11.position = CGPoint(x: ground10.position.x+ground11.size.width, y: 10)
                    worldNode.addChild(ground11)



                    ground12.xScale = 0.7
                    ground12.yScale = 0.7
                    ground12.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: ground12.size)
                    ground12.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = BodyType.Ground.rawValue
                    ground12.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = BodyType.Player.rawValue
                    ground12.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = BodyType.Player.rawValue
                    ground12.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
                    ground12.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
                    ground12.position = CGPoint(x: ground11.position.x+ground12.size.width, y: 10)
                   worldNode.addChild(ground12)


                //if ground13.parent == nil {
                    ground13.xScale = 0.7
                    ground13.yScale = 0.7
                    ground13.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: ground13.size)
                    ground13.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = BodyType.Ground.rawValue
                    ground13.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = BodyType.Player.rawValue
                    ground13.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = BodyType.Player.rawValue
                    ground13.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
                    ground13.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
                    ground13.position = CGPoint(x: ground12.position.x+ground13.size.width, y: 10)
                    worldNode.addChild(ground13)
                //}


    }//end of Make Block   
}
```

> This makes just enough to fill the ground of the screen of a iphone 6

Comment: Seems like you need to make the terrain generation process either "leapfrog" or as your player moves along and hits a detection line that spawns in a new ground node adds it to the scene, and then maybe just forgets about it?  Also, are these all going to be identical terrain, or will it be able to reuse say 2 for the "leapfrog", only having terrain as the player moves around?

Comment: Create multiple ground textures that are different to each other (but the same size probably) that can be placed next to any other without an obvious join. Then working from one side of the screen to the other, place enough to fill the screen and one extra tile. After scrolling the screen, check if a tile has gone off-screen. if so, remove it and generate a new tile ready to be scrolled onto the screen.

Comment: Subclass SKSpriteNode to create your ground, so you can easily spawn new ground sprites - pages of duplicated code looks bad and is inflexible.

Comment: @EthanHofton You should really use loops to create ground nodes :)

Answer (score 0):

I have [code on github](https://github.com/gooddoug/ParallaxScrollingExamples) that creates an infinitely scrolling background. It is concerned with making a parallax background, but you can see the code in there for having it scroll infinitely. The trick is to create enough ground nodes to cover the width, plus a couple extras for each end. When the one at the left moves completely off the screen (by checking it's `origin.x + size.width` value against the origin of the view) you pick it up and move it to the far right. Conversely, if you are moving the other direction, and find that your last node is completely off the screen, you pick up the one furthest right and move it to the beginning.

When done correctly it looks smooth and is fairly simple.